# Docking a detached view with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, view

When I drag a view outside of the Workbench window, the view becomes a detached view.

The Eclipse help says (Workbench User Guide -> Tasks -> Working with views and editors -> Detaching views and editors): "To restore the view to be shown inside of the Workbench window, drag the view tab into the Workbench window."

With my configuration (Windows 7; 2 screens; pushing the maximise button maximises Eclipse in one of the two screens) this does not work.

I have to use "Windows -> Restore Perspective ..." to get the view back inside the Workbench.

Is there an other way for reattaching a detached view?

Comment: Do you drag & drop the tab (i.e. not the window)?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I missunderstood: for detaching you move all tabs at the same time - for reattaching you have to move one tab after the other.

Comment: @Njol This should be an answer - it works.

Comment: "Windows -> Reset Perspective ..." was the only thing that worked for me with Neon on Ubuntu14.04. Some GUI bug (probably) made it impossible to reattach the views once detached.

Answer (score 62):

As per njol's answer above, once you have your tab detached (showing as floating outside of your Eclipse IDE), simply **click on the tab (not on the title of detached tab window)** and drag.  Then you will see mouse cursor change showing you where you can drop it to attach the tab to IDE.
[image]

Comment: I can confirm this works on Mac as well. (STS 4.12.1, OS 13.12.1).

Answer (score 38):

You have to move each tab from the detached views window to the side of a tab in the main window. (The fact that we should move it to the *side* of another tab was a detail that took me a while to grasp.) A GIF would help:

[image: Dragging a tab to the right side of another tab in the main window]

Note the little green vertical line that appears beside the "Servers" tab — it indicates you've dragged the tab in the right place:

[image: Little green vertical line]

* *The red circle only appears when I am pressing the mouse button. It was added by an external program to highlight when the mouse is pressed; it will not appear to you.*

Answer (score 14):

From @zvezda's comment above,

```
"Windows -> Reset Perspective ..."
```

was the *only* method that worked for me (using Mars on Fedora 22).

Comment: In Mars.2 you cannot drag a view window to a different location in Eclipse.  If you drag a tab you get a detached window.

Comment: Same situation applies for me and Eclipse Neon.2